# Como puedo mejorar mi gráfica de boxplot en este caso?

Tags: python, seaborn

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito mejorar las 'cajas' de este boxplot ya que el rango de datos es muy amplio. Como sugiere hacerlo para tener una correcta visualización?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tratar los datos y eliminar los outliers (ir probrando a eliminar los valores mayores de 20.000 y ver si sale bien, si no probar con 15.000, 10.000, etc.). Eso hará que el eje "y" no sea tan amplio.

Comment: Perfecto lo intento gracias